# Как реализовать регистрацию и идентификацию пользователя на сайте с использованием Metamask

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, blockchain

Хочу реализовать идентификацию пользователя на сайте с помощью Metamask.

Пишу сайт на asp.net mvc.

Провёл больше двух дней поиска информации и нашел только один [пример](https://medium.com/coinmonks/secure-asp-net-core-2-api-with-ethereum-blockchain-88001d5ddb6)

Я буду благодарен за любые рабочие фрагменты кода(примеры).

Comment: Привет, интересная идея. Подписался на вопрос. Только вот еще было бы хорошо, если бы Вы подправили ссылку на статью о Metamask.

Comment: Привет, поправил немного.

Comment: Добрый день. Тысячу лет был на этом сайте. У Вас проблема с формированием JWT, установить инструменты именно в asp.net mvc или вообще запрос отправить не можете?

Comment: @Denis640Kb причем тут jwt?

Comment: @Grundy Вы ссылку почитали, что в примере поста?

Comment: @Denis640Kb, бегло, не увидел сначала там про jwt, но он не особо и нужен